# Grails: println only works sometimes or something

Tags: grails, groovy, metaclass, expando, println

I make a brand new grails project and put this in the bootstrap:

```
ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()

Integer.metaClass.precision = {->return 1}
println 3.precision()
println "rofl"
println 15.precision()
```

And it does what I expect, run-app prints:

```
1
rofl
1
```

But if i take out the `println "rofl"` it won't print that second one.  It just prints one 1 without the rofl... WTF?

Again, becasue this doesn't make any sense to me, this code:

```
ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()

Integer.metaClass.precision = {->return 1}
println 3.precision()
//println "rofl"
println 15.precision()
```

prints:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Mikey, I can't think of a reason why.  Can you try in a different environment?  I just tried this quickly under Groovy Version: 1.8.0 JVM: 1.6.0_20, Win7 and Grails 2 BootStrap and a Grails Controller action and sorry to say "it works on mine".  So all I can think is that its somehow related to the version you are using or how it is setup.  How are you running this?

Comment: What are you using the controller for?  I have all the code in the bootstrap.  Also I have upgraded my grails and groovy.  Still not working.

Comment: Just tried it in the controller for kicks but I tried Bootstrap for sure.  I'm not sure on STS, are you running from STS or just command line or interactive?  All I can think is to try from different places, but I'm guessing that is what you have trying for the last few hours.

Comment: Actually upgrading grails to 2.0 is kicking my ass.

Comment: So I did grails upgrade on my project and its destroyed.  Now I can't get anything grails 2.0 to run.... get ready for some other questions, SO!!

Comment: Upgraded grails to 2.0 and groovy to 1.8, changed JVM from IcedTea 6 to Oracle 6 to Oracle 7.  Same results.  Tried on my work PC: win7 home jvm 6 grails 1.3.7 also same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ubuntu default setting and has nothing to do with JVM.  The console won't repeat lines if they are the same.  Will update this answer when I remember how to turn it off.